# SQL Developer and DB2 errors

Tags: db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'd like to use SQL Developer with DB2, I was able to connect and I canned execute my queries, but when I have an error, I cannot know witch error is. SQL Developer shown me only the error code, not the message. There is the way to know the error I have?

`EDIT:`

For example, launching this query:

```
Select * from WrongTable
```

other programs says:

```
ERROR[42704][IBM][DB2/NT64] SQL0204N "USERNAME.WRONGTABLE" è un nome non definito
```

sqldeveloper limits its report to the error nr only:

```
Errore alla riga del comando : 1 colonna : 1
Report errori -
Errore SQL: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=USERNAME.WRONGTABLE, DRIVER=4.19.49
```

Thank you.

Comment: In the database connection string or URL, append `;retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=1;`  . Notice the semicolon prefix and suffix.

Comment: Hy mao, I tryed to put that flag in the connection string puting it after the db name (host: «hostIp», port: «###» Database: «DBName;retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=1;») but it throws the following error: [jcc][10165][10036][4.19.49] URL Syntax not valid: sdbc:db2://hostIp:###/DBName;retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=1;. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815

Comment: See answer for clarification. My remark presumed you already had at least one property, which evidently you do not, hence you would use `DBName:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=1;`

Comment: Sorry, with the colon it doesn't retrieve the connection error. But the result is the same (no messages retrieved). I have the the db2 drivers (db2jcc4) in 4.19.49 version, and db2 is 10.5 sp7. Maybe this is an old drivers?

Comment: Edit your question to show in plain text an example of the error code that you say has no message attached when you enable the setting.

Comment: For your query, my SQL-Developer (17.2.0.188) when configured with `:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=YES;` after the databasename  ( YES, 1, and true should all give the same result) returns the message: ` "USERNAME.WRONGTABLE" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.23.42" ` .  Remember to save the settings change, disconnect, reconnect. Verify it is set. Try value YES and true in case there is some version issue. Your V10.5 should also support this, even with your jdbc driver version I think, as this setting is not new.

Comment: Ok, thank you, with the YES parameter, it works well. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL syntax for connecting to Db2 with type-4 jdbc drivers is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052342.html).

The property that controls how much information is returned with `getMessage()` is called `retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage`, and its default value is disabled ( false , 0 ).  Set it to value 1 (or YES, or true )to enable more details on errors.

You can append many properties after the `database name` in the `Database` field, on the Oracle SQL-Developer connection properties. Express each property in the form x=y , each x=y pair is separated by a semi-colon and the final one is terminated by a semi-colon, and the first property is prefixed by colon immediately after the database name.

For example, suppose the database name is `sample` and I wanted three additional properties, the I would put this in the `Database` field in Oracle-SQL-developer:

`sample:useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics=No;securityMechanism=11;retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=1;`

If value 1 does not give the expected result, use value YES although they should be equivalent. Remember to SAVE the setting change, disconnect from the database, reconnect , before retrying your queries to assess the change.

Many other properties are available, see many related pages in the documentation , some properties are common to all target Db2 platforms, other properties are specific to Db2-LUW, or Db2-Z/OS, or Informix etc, so read the docs carefully. Some properties can be set by code after the connection is already established.